# javascript split, each, check if exists in select if not add option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone see what im doing wrong here?

I am trying to split `tag_filter`, then for each of the `tag_filter` values, I would like to check if the option value already exists in `tag_select_dropdown_filter`. If it does not exist then add option to `tag_select_dropdown_filter`.

```
var tag_filter = new1,new2,new3;
var arraylist = tag_filter.Split(",");

jQuery.each(arraylist, function(index, item) {

   if ($('select#tag_select_dropdown_filter option[value="'+item+'"]').length) {
     // it exists
   } else { var o = new Option("option text", item);
     $(o).html("option text");
     $("#tag_select_dropdown_filter").append(o);
   }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some typos/mistakes in your code:

- I think `tag_filter` should be declared like this: `var tag_filter = 'new1,new2,new3';`. In your code you assign it just the value of the *variable* `new1`.
- [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with a lower `s` at the start.
- The `length` property is even set, when the query before does not return a result.. So check, whether it is larger than 1.

The correct code could look something like this:

```
var tag_filter = 'new1,new2,new3';
var arraylist = tag_filter.split(",");

jQuery.each(arraylist, function(index, item) {

   if ($('select#tag_select_dropdown_filter option[value="'+item+'"]').length > 0) {
     // it exists
   } else { 
     var o = new Option("option text", item);
     $(o).html("option text");
     $("#tag_select_dropdown_filter").append(o);
   }

});
```

I assume you get `tag_filter` from somewhere else in the code. If not, it would be easier to just use this:

```
// if new1 to new3 shall be strings
var array_list = [ 'new1', 'new2', 'new3' ];

// if new1 to new3 are variables
var array_list = [ new1, new2, new3 ];
```

Comment: sorry was typo just to represent what tag_filter was. tag_filter is defined elsewhere in my code.

Comment: Brilliant this worked, by changing to lower-case s for split and adding > 0 after .length. I also have to change $(o).html("option text"); ---->> $(o).html(item); --- Thank you very much

Comment: How could I incorporate a sort so it inserts the option alphabetically.

Comment: @Codded You could use [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), before inserting the nodes.

Answer (score 2):

You can only split strings, so it would have to be:

```
var tag_filter = 'new1,new2,new3';
```

If those are in fact variables, you could do:

```
var arraylist = [ new1, new2, new3 ];
```

and it should be `string.split()` (lowercase), unless that is some custom function you've decided not to show us ?

Comment: sorry was typo just to represent what tag_filter was. tag_filter is elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing the issue is that tag_filer should be a string like this:

```
var tag_filter = "new1,new2,new3";
```

Comment: sorry was typo just to represent what tag_filter was. tag_filter is elsewhere in my code.